# How to send a random string via Inline Telegram commands?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have created a bot (using `python-telegram-bot`) that upon choosing a type of query, the bot should randomly choose one of the available strings as the reply.

My function to create replies is as follows:

```
def generate_reply():
    replies = """
              Hello
              Goodbye
              Thanks!
              Your welcome!
              See you around!""".splitlines()
    r = random.choice(replies).strip()
    return r
```

And the functions to reply to the users are as follows:

```
#Inline Reply
def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = [InlineQueryResultArticle(id=uuid4(), title="Interact",
                                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                                                generate_reply()))]

    update.inline_query.answer(results)

#Normal reply
def reply(update, context):
   update.message.reply_text(generate_reply())
```

And after creating the bot I add it to the bot using:

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("reply", reply))
dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery))
```

when I use `/reply` in chat it works as intended, but wherever I use an inline command in a chat with another user or a group, the random choice apparently stops working.How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to my question. Apparently Telegram caches the answers to similar inline queries for some time. For this to work correctly you should set `cache_time` to something you'd like, in my case 0.

```
#Inline Reply
def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = [InlineQueryResultArticle(id=uuid4(), title="Interact",
                                        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                                                generate_reply()))]

    update.inline_query.answer(results, cache_time=0)
```